# Created directory with for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have these files. Imagine that each "test" represent the name of one server:

```
test10.txt
test11.txt
test12.txt
test13.txt
test14.txt
test15.txt
test16.txt
test17.txt
test18.txt
test19.txt
test1.txt
test20.txt
test21.txt
test22.txt
test23.txt
test24.txt
test25.txt
test26.txt
test27.txt
test28.txt
test29.txt
test2.txt
test30.txt
test31.txt
test32.txt
test33.txt
test34.txt
test35.txt
test36.txt
test37.txt
test38.txt
test39.txt
test3.txt
test40.txt
test4.txt
test5.txt
test6.txt
test7.txt
test8.txt
test9.txt
```

In each txt file, I have this type of data:

```
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;1024.00;136.37;/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;5248.00;4230.53;/usr
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;2560.00;481.66;/var
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;3584.00;67.65;/tmp
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd5;256.00;26.13;/home
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;1024.00;476.04;/opt
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd5;384.00;0.38;/usr/xxx
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;21.39;/xxx
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;512.00;216.84;/opt
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;128.00;21.46;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd8;256.00;75.21;/usr/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd7;384.00;186.87;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd6;256.00;0.63;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;128.00;0.37;/admin
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;179.14;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;2176.00;492.93;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;256.00;114.83;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd9;256.00;41.73;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;3200.00;954.28;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd10;256.00;0.93;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd10;64.00;1.33;/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;1664.00;501.64;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;112.32;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd9;2176.00;1223.1;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd11;22784.00;12325.8;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd12;256.00;2.36;/
2019-10-14-06-00;/dev/hd12;1024.00;137.18;/
2019-10-14-06-00;/dev/hd1;256.00;2.36;/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;1024.00;136.37;/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;5248.00;4230.53;/usr
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;2560.00;481.66;/var
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;3584.00;67.65;/tmp
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd5;256.00;26.13;/home
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;1024.00;476.04;/opt
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd5;384.00;0.38;/usr/xxx
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;21.39;/xxx
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;512.00;216.84;/opt
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;128.00;21.46;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd8;256.00;75.21;/usr/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd7;384.00;186.87;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd6;256.00;0.63;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;128.00;0.37;/admin
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;179.14;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd3;2176.00;492.93;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;256.00;114.83;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd9;256.00;41.73;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;3200.00;954.28;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd10;256.00;0.93;/var/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd10;64.00;1.33;/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd2;1664.00;501.64;/opt/
2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd4;256.00;112.32;/opt/
```

I would like to create a directory for each server, create in each directory a txt file for each FS and put in these txt files each lines which correspond to the FS.

For that, I've tried loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=(ls *.txt | cut -d'.' -f1)
for d in $directory
do
        if [ ! -d $d ]
        then
                mkdir $d
        fi
done

for i in $(cat *.txt)
do
        file=$(echo $i | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | cut -d'/' -f3 )
        data=$(echo $i | awk -F';' '{print $2}' )
        echo $i | grep -w $data >> /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/${directory/${file}.txt
done
```

But this loop doesn't work properly. The directories are created but not the file inside each directory.

I would like something like :

test1/hd1.txt ( with each line which for the hd1 fs in the hd1.txt)

And same thing for each server.

Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: "this loop doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. Are you getting errors? Or unexpected results? Please describe those in detail and provide the exact error message, if any. The missing closing parenthesis on the third line may be the culprit, though

Comment: @ForceBru I've corrected to be more clear.

Comment: @MaxMuster I've add some informations about my server list. For each "testX.txt", test represent the name of one of my server.

Comment: In the second last line of the script, ```${directory``` should be ```${directory}```. Is that a typo?

Comment: What do you call FS ? For example in folder `test01` you have a file `test01.txt` and in the file you have a entry like  `2019-10-14-00-00;/dev/hd1;1024.00;136.37;/`

Comment: Just a question: you are trying to write to the file, called `/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/${directory}/${file}.txt` (I added the second `}`), can you do a `touch` of that file and verify if the file gets created?

Comment: @MaxMuster FS are /dev/hd1, /dev/hd2 etc...
So I would like to create a directory with the name of server ( here represented by "test"), in each directory create a txt file for each fs ( hd1.txt, hd2.txt, hd3.txt etc... ) and put in these txt file, each line which correspond to the FS. ( In hd1.txt, each line with /dev/hd1, in hd2.txt, each line with /dev/hd2 ) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for src in *.txt; do
    # start a subshell so we don't need to cd back afterwards
    # make "$src" be stdin before cd, so we don't need full path
    # be careful that in subshell only awk reads from stdin
    (
        # extract server name to use as directory
        dir=/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/"${src%.txt}"

        # chain with "&&" so failures don't cause bad files
        mkdir -p "$dir" &&
        cd "$dir" &&
        awk -F \; '{ split($2, dev, "/"); print > dev[3]".txt" }'
    ) < "$src"
done
```

- The awk script reads lines delimited by semi-colons.
- It splits the second field on slashes to extract the device name (assumption is that the devices always have form: `/dev/`**name**
- Finally, the `>` sends output to the relevant file.

---

For reference, you can make your script work by doing `directory=$(...)`; adding the prefix to `mkdir` (assuming the prefix directories already exist); closing the reference `${directory}`; and quoting all variable references for safety:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

directory=$(ls *.txt | cut -d'.' -f1)
for d in "$directory"
do
        if [ ! -d "$d" ]
        then
                mkdir /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/"$d"
        fi
done

for i in $(cat *.txt)
do
        file=$(echo "$i" | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | cut -d'/' -f3 )
        data=$(echo $i | awk -F';' '{print $2}' )
        echo "$i" | grep -w "$data" >> /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/"${directory}"/"${file}".txt
done
```

Comment: Please, could you explain what means the "%" in "${src%.txt}"?

Comment: `${parameter%word}` is normal [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score -2):

```
for file in `ls *.txt`
do
    echo ${file}
    directory=`echo ${file} | cut -d'.' -f1`
    #echo ${directory}
    if [ ! -d ${directory} ]
    then
        mkdir ${directory}
    fi
    FS=`cat ${file} | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | cut -d'/' -f3`
    #echo $FS
    for f in $FS
    do
        cat ${file} |grep -w -e $f > ${directory}/${f}.txt
    done
done
```

Explanation:

For each file in the current directory, the outer for loop will run.

In the loop for the selected file, a respective directory will be created first.

Next using the FS variable we take all the possible file systems from that selected file.

Finally, an inner loop will be run using the FS types to grep and create separate file system files in the directory.

Comment: Please read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.